# unexpected end of file error on line 35

Tags: php, mysql

The error is

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected end of file in C:\xampp\htdocs\project\inc\header.inc.php on line 35

The code below is for the header file where the error is meant to be:

```
<?php 
include ("./inc/connect.inc.php");
session_start();
if (!isset($_SESSION["user_login"])){
}
else
{
header("location: home.php")
?>


<html>
     <head>
         <title>Memory Lane</title>
         <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./css/style.css"
 </head>
     <body>
         <div class="HeaderMenu">
         <div id="wrapper">
             <div class="logo">
                 <img src="./Image/Memorylane_logo.jpg"/>
             </div>
             <div class="search_box"> 
                <form action="search.php" method="GET" ID="search"> 
                <input type="text" name="q" size="60" placeholder="Search ..."/>
                </form>
             </div>
             <div id="menu"> 
             <a href ="#"/>Home</a>
             <a href ="#"/>About</a>
             <a href ="#"/>Sign Up</a>
             <a href ="#"/>Sign In</a>
             </div>
         </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're messing a closing `}` here :

```
<?php 
include ("./inc/connect.inc.php");
session_start();
if (!isset($_SESSION["user_login"])){
}
else
{
header("location: home.php"); // <-- You were also missing a semicolon here 
exit; // <-- and an exit is a good thing to use after an header
} // <--- You should add this one
?>
```

also if you indent your code it'll be easier to catch missing blosing brackets like below :

```
<?php 
   include ("./inc/connect.inc.php");
   session_start();
   if (!isset($_SESSION["user_login"])){
    //Also putting some code here would be a good idea
   } else {
     header("location: home.php");
     exit;
   }
?>
```

Comment: Need to close the `header` line in that case `;`. Also an exit should be added.

Comment: Thanks, it is working now

Answer (score 1):

You're missing a closing `}` at the end of the file to close the `else` block:

```
         </div>
    </div>
<?php
}

?>
```

Edit: Noticed that you're trying to do a redirect. In that case, the `}` should be right after the line that says:

```
header("location: home.php")
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your with below code. else end is not mentioned and after this line `header("location: home.php")` give a semi-clone.

```
<?php 
include ("./inc/connect.inc.php");
session_start();
if (!isset($_SESSION["user_login"])){
}
else
{
header("location: home.php");
}
?>
```